# ZendDebugger cannot open libssl.so.0.9.8 in Mint 12

Tags: php, linux, zend-debugger

I installed apache and php, now to use the ZendDebugger I and modified the php.ini how it was described.
When I start apache, I get following error message in the log:

```
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/zend/ZendDebugger.so:  libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked and there is only libssl.so.1.0.0 available on my machine.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed to get ZendDebugger working.

Thanks in advance,
max

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously the libssl.so.0.9.8 was missing.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8
```

and a restart did the trick