# Zend Debugger will not load

Tags: php, apache, zend-debugger

I'm trying to set up remote **PHP** debugging with [Zend Debugger](http://www.zend.com/en/solutions/php-debugging/) (I tried installing [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org), but it conflicts with ionCube Loader). I've followed the [instructions](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=962#p4190) for Linux. In particular, I've added the following lines to the end of `/etc/php.ini`:

```
zend_extension=ZendDebugger.so
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1,173.181.57.148
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

I don't have an absolute path to `ZendDebugger.so` because it's in extension_dir (/usr/lib64/php/modules).

After restarting Apache, there isn't anything different in `phpinfo()`. Also, I can't find any problems in the Apache error log (/var/log/httpd/error_log).

Is there anything that I missed?

Thanks,
Shane.

Answer (score 2):

For archive purpose:

> sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8

and then restart. In Ubuntu 12.04 works fine.

All credits to [ZendDebugger cannot open libssl.so.0.9.8 in Mint 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441729/zenddebugger-cannot-open-libssl-so-0-9-8-in-mint-12)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to diagnose the problem by doing "php -m", which showed me the error message:

```
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendDebugger.so:  libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

With the error message, I was able to begin troubleshooting...

Zend Debugger appears to be looking for the "libssl.so.0.9.8" shared object (a very old version), and for some reason doesn't see the current version "libssl3.so". I was able to create a symlink between the two.

Shane.